# Селезень и селезенка

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

Есть шутка, что жена селезня - селезенка. А, в самом деле, есть ли какая-то связь между этими словами?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Селезёнка** - от праслав. *selezenь наряду с* selzenь обычно связывается с и.-е. названием селезенки, хотя относительно исходной формы согласия не достигнуто. Маценауэр принимает родство с *селезень* (по цвету оперения). Существует версия об уточнении праславянской формы *sьlеzеnа, а не* selzena, иначе ожидалось бы вост.-слав. *солоз- (Вайан).

Версий происхождения слова **СЕЛЕЗЕНЬ** существует несколько: по цвету оперения ('голубой', 'седой'), звукоподражательная версия. Фасмер их считает неудовлетворительными. Акад. Трубачев называет еще версию  происхождения слова селезень от названия растения сљез (серб.-хорв.) 'мальва'.

Возможно, связь между селезнем и селезенкой и существует, но весомых доказательств этой связи нет.